# How to see or download only 1st page of any online PDF without downloading whole PDF?

Tags: windows-xp, pdf, portable

I need to note the title inside a PDF (which is always on the first page of each PDF), from 300 PDF files that are online.  All of the files are big, above 5 MB.  How can I see or download only the 1st page of each one?

I need a solution for Windows XP 32 bit that does not require installing software, preferably no-cost.

For example http://www.adobe.com/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/plugin_apps_developer_guide.pdf

Answer (score 1):

This may help: [Ajax DocumentViewer - Browser helper tool](http://www.ajaxdocumentviewer.com/toolbar.asp).

> Bring the power of AJAXDocumentViewer
>   to your desktop right within your
>   browser. Add a small module into your
>   existing Microsoft IE or Mozilla
>   Firefox browser and make browsing of
>   documents easier and faster. **No need
>   to download the documents** when
>   browsing different websites, simply
>   click on the AJAXDocumentViewer logo
>   to preview the document right within
>   your browser. Reduce document download
>   times and eliminate the need to even
>   download the documents to your
>   computer.
>
> Supports MS Office Documents (doc,
>   xls, ppt, docx, xlsx, pptx), Open
>   Office Documents, Sun Office
>   Documents, PDF & TIF images.

[image]

Comment: not working on Firefox 3.6

Comment: In your question, you didn't ask it as for Firefox. You just said WinXP. So IE8 is still an option.

Comment: ok will try in IE

Answer (score 0):

I would you this http://blog.arpitnext.com/gpdf

Benefits of Google Docs Viewer:

- Safe. You don’t need to use potentially vulnerable tools to open PDF files.
- Fast! No more wait to download PDF files. GDocs Viewer processes pdf files with super speed. It feels like visiting another webpage. :)
- Best for slow connections.